# text between 2 words with some lines before patterns

Tags: command-line, text-processing

how can I find lines between two words with 3 lines before START_WORD in **sed** or **grep** or ...

for example output from a command is:

```
my name is
Mansour
and I confuse to
use sed
or grep for
piping my command output
to get 
my ideal output
```

and I want my out after piping the command with sed or grep on START_WORD=command and END_WORD=ideal:

```
and I confuse to
use sed
or grep for
piping my command output
to get 
my ideal output
```

Comment: please [edit] your question to add sample input and your desired output from that..

Comment: Some example input and output would really help; your question is indecipherable so far

Comment: @kos I need 3 lines before my start word pattern

Comment: Ah my bad sorry, I didn't read carefully.

Comment: Do `grep -Pzo '(?s)\n\K([^\n]*\n){3}[^\n]*command[^\n]*\n.*?\n[^\n]*ideal[^\n]*(?=\n)' file.txt` ..if the question is reopened, let me know..i will put it as an answer with details..

Comment: @heemayl Thank you very much, it works perfect

Comment: If my or kos's answer helped, please select it as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
grep -Pzo '(?s)\n\K([^\n]*\n){3}[^\n]*command[^\n]*\n.*?\n[^\n]*ideal[^\n]*(?=\n)' file.txt
```

- `-P` enables Perl Compatible Regex, `-z` makes the input data separated on ASCII NUL rather than usual newline, `-o` lets up take only matched portion
- `(?s)` is DOTALL modifier, this enables us to match newline (`\n`) with `.` token
- `\n\K([^\n]*\n){3}` matches `\n` at first and then discards the match `\K`, `([^\n]*\n){3}` matches three lines before line containing `command`
- `[^\n]*command[^\n]*\n.*?\n[^\n]*ideal[^\n]*(?=\n)` matches all lines starting from line having `command` till the line containing `ideal`

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
my name is
Mansour
and I confuse to
use sed
or grep for
piping my command output
to get 
my ideal output

% grep -Pzo '(?s)\n\K([^\n]*\n){3}[^\n]*command[^\n]*\n.*?\n[^\n]*ideal[^\n]*(?=\n)' file.txt
and I confuse to
use sed
or grep for
piping my command output
to get 
my ideal output
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using Perl:

```bsh
perl -ne 'BEGIN{ my @buffer } unshift(@buffer, $_); splice(@buffer, 4); if(/\bcommand\b/) { print(reverse(@buffer)); while(<>) { print(); /\bideal\b/ && exit } exit }' file
```

- `n`: causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk:

  ```perl
  LINE:
    while (<>) {
        ...             # your program goes here
    }
  ```
- `-e`: may be used to enter one line of program.
- `BEGIN{ my @buffer } unshift(@buffer, $_); splice(@buffer, 4); if(/\bcommand\b/) { print(reverse(@buffer)); while(<>) { print(); /\bideal\b/ && exit } exit }`: inserts the current line at the start of a buffer and truncates the buffer to a length of 4; if the current line contains the word `command`, prints the buffer in reverse order and iterates through all the remaining lines printing them; if a printed line contained `ideal` or the end of file had been reached, exits.

```bsh
% cat file
my name is
Mansour
and I confuse to
use sed
or grep for
piping my command output
to get 
my ideal output
% perl -ne 'BEGIN{ my @buffer } unshift(@buffer, $_); splice(@buffer, 4); if(/\bcommand\b/) { print(reverse(@buffer)); while(<>) { print(); /\bideal\b/ && exit } exit }' file
and I confuse to
use sed
or grep for
piping my command output
to get 
my ideal output
%
```

Comment: You love `perl`..don't you? :)

Comment: @heemayl Sure! When the other tools don't suffice or `grep` has been taken already... ;) (sometimes I prefer it to AWK because it's easier to manipulate arrays)

Comment: Yeah..`awk` knows its job very well..may be someday i will start learning it from you :)

Comment: @heemayl You could have better teachers, trust me :) Yes AWK is very useful when processing something which has a natural records/fields structure, knowing it and using it when appropriate in place of `sed` / `grep` is like stopping to cut paper using the knife and starting to do that using the scissors, if you know what I mean. :)